# Show $E((X-Y)Y)=0$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, conditional-expectation

> If $EX^2<\infty$ and $E(X|\mathcal G)$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable then $E(X|\mathcal G)=EX$

There is one step in the proof which I don't understand, set $Y=E(X|\mathcal G)$ and then why is $E((X-Y)Y)=0$, from a theorem I know that $Y\in\mathcal F$ is such that $E(X-Y)^2$ is minimal

Comment: What is the relationship between the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[(X-Y)Y]&=E[E((X-Y)Y|\mathcal{G})]\\&=E[YE(X-Y|\mathcal{G})]\\&=E[Y(E(X|\mathcal{G})-E(X|\mathcal{G}))]\\&=0.
\end{align}
The first equality uses the Law of Iterated Expectations, the second "factoring out what is known," and the third linearity plus another application of "factoring out what is known."

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks for the edit.